# Should water heaters be turned off (for safety) when not in use?

Tags: water-heater

Is there any safety concern regarding leaving water heaters on 24/7?

Comment: If you turn it off for too long, while leaving water in it, then it can rust out and leak.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how long is too long? I presume you are talking about months on end, or maybe even years?

Comment: @EngrStudent: why would the heater being off make a difference in rust? There's water in the tank 24/7 either way.

Comment: Science: There is always some micro-organisms and solutes in public water.  Acids are one of the big waste-products for anaerobic micro-organisms.  Flowing water has less chance to build up higher concentrations of acids before it is moved downstream.  Hot water is more sterile, it makes it harder for micro-organisms to grow in the first place.  How I know: experience, and ~$1000 in surprise bills, with a chance to debate with HOA whether repair for walls damaged by water came out of my pocket or theirs.  not remotely fun at all.

Comment: @EngrStudent: I'm not sure I buy your reasoning. First of all, tap water should have very little "micro-organisms" in it, certainly not enough to be affecting the ph of the water. Secondly, tap water sends to be a little on the basic side anyway. Finally if the water did somehow get acidic I think you would notice it long before it started causing damage to anything. I can't find anything online that remotely corroborates your statements about acid or rust.

Comment: @HenryJackson - [dummies link](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-prevent-rust-in-your-water-heater.html) So it is glass on normal steel.  The cracks change the behavior.  The rust pulls oxygen out of the water, liberating hydrogen, making it more acidic.  [ph friendly bacteria](http://education.seattlepi.com/types-bacteria-living-acidic-ph-3540.html) are very common, and lower the ph of their evironment.  [Siderophores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siderophore#Soil_and_surface_water) are how ph-loving bacteria get their iron - which is critical for life.

Comment: @EngrStudent: I still don't see anything how a room-temperature water heater leads to either acidic water or increased rusting. I think turning off a water heater when not in use (e.g. on vacation) is extremely common and not at all a hazard.

Comment: @HenryJackson - good news.  Smart devices are coming out all the time.  The IoT/smart-home/connected water heater is going to make that information grossly publicly accessible.  Third party companies are going to sell a $30 widget that gives alerts you can act to, and maybe even wrap the device in insurance.  When they want to sell more $30 products - they will put the data into marketing.  I went to school with schmucks who engineered planned/timed obsolescence into their designs.  I think IoT might make a lot of that hard (and lucrative) work obsolete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No: water heaters are designed to be left on 24/7/365. You might turn one off if you're leaving for a vacation to save energy, but safety isn't part of the decision.

Comment: Some people put timers on the incoming power to cut down on power consumption.